# Unique type ID in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

I need to have an unique ID for any type in C++ for a variant type. Is this code reliable for getting the ID? I don't care to have same ID for same type between multiple runs. Sorry for typos/formatting, I wrote the code on my phone and tested on Ideone.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Counter
{
    static size_t value;
};

size_t Counter::value = 1;

template<typename T>
struct TypeID : private Counter
{
    static size_t value()
    {
        static size_t value = Counter::value++;
        return value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << TypeID<int>::value() << " " << TypeID<int*>::value() << " " << TypeID<Counter>::value() << " " << TypeID<int>::value();

return 0;
}
```

PS: I use this because `std::type_index/std::type_info::hash` may have the same value for different types (probably not in practice).

Comment: Use [`type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index/operator_cmp). (Yours is a standard problem with a standard solution from the standard library, which is this one.)

Comment: @not-a-user it is bound to typeid, therefore can't be used with rtti disabled

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Re. the algorithm, IMO it looks safe, with only two caveats:

- I'm not sure that it's thread-safe.
- It looks safe, because of the "one-definition rule". I worried that if multiple source files ('translation units') invoke `TypeID<int*>::value()` they might each get their own copy of the type; however I think that the "one-definition rule" requires the linker to collapse the multiple types into one.
  Furthermore I think that's not just a common good-practice (implemented by some compilers but not others), but is actually required by the standard.
  But I don't think it will be safe if your program includes multiple DLLs: each DLL is built separately so it would get its own copy of a TypeID instantiation.

Re. the code, I don't see why TypeID is a subclass of Counter; it works equally well like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct TypeID // : private Counter
{
    static size_t value()
    {
        static size_t value = Counter::value++;
        return value;
    }
};
```

Perhaps you used inheritance to try to protect the Counter value; if so that would be more effective with the protected keyword:

```
struct Counter
{
protected:
    static size_t value;
};
```

That's still imperfect (because anyone can subclass Counter). So an all-in-one version would be more fool-proof:

```
class TypeID
{
    static size_t counter;

public:
    template<typename T>
    static size_t value()
    {
        static size_t id = counter++;
        return id;
    }
};
```

... invoked like this ...

```
TypeID::value<int>()
```

---

> I think a spinlock + atomics will do the job. Do you think it is enough?

I found that for some (but perhaps not all) compilers and compiler options, initialization of statics is thread-safe: for detail, see [Are (initializing) function static variables thread-safe in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1270927/49942). In that case, using an atomic `Counter::value` is sufficient (because the initialization of each instance `value` is thread-safe).

If such a feature isn't in your compiler, then IMO you need:

- a lockguard in the value() method
- and the lockguard must lock an already-constructed lock (perhaps not a separate lock for each T)
- but given a 'global' lockguard, it wouldn't be necessary to also use an atomic `Counter::value`

Comment: Thanks! Good catch with thread safety! I will use atomic increment for the value:)

Comment: If it has to be thread-safe then atomic increment isn't enough. Initializing a static variable in a function is implicitly `if (!initialized) id = etc.` and that test for `if (!initialized)` isn't thread-safe.

Comment: I think a spinlock + atomics will do the job. Do you think it is enough?

Comment: @Felics I edited my answer to try to reply to your comment.

Answer (score 17):

Here is my lightweight solution that involves no operations at run time:

```
template<typename T>
struct type { static void id() { } };

template<typename T>
size_t type_id() { return reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&type<T>::id); }

struct A { };

int main ()
{
    cout << type_id<int>() << " " << type_id<int*>() << " "
         << type_id<A>() << " " << type_id<int>() << endl;
}
```

The type id of type `T` is nothing but the address of function `type<T>::id`, re-interpreted as a number. Being a static method, there is a unique such function per type. These addresses are assigned by the linker (I think), so they remain constant between different runs. The overhead in executable size is linear in the number of type ids requested (that is, the number of instantiations of `type<T>`).

This solution has been tested in gcc and clang, and works correctly across different compilation units, i.e. you get the same unique type id for the same type in different compilation units. However, I cannot quite explain why/how this happens.

`type_id()` is easily inlined, so has no run-time cost. However, since it contains `reinterpret_cast` (and since the function address is not known to the compiler), it cannot be made `constexpr`. But I don't see this as a problem: if you want to use something e.g. as a template argument, you can use the type directly instead of its id. The id is for run-time use only.

My original implementation is using `const void*` as the return type of `type_id()`, so I know it has the same size as any pointer. I adapted it to `size_t` to fit the question. I think this is still safe, but I can't see why `const void*` wouldn't be fair enough.

By the way, because I haven't used it very much, I'd be happy to hear if there may be problems with this approach.

Comment: `However, I cannot quite explain why/how this happens.` -- `type<T>::id` is a function (method). Apparently there's a so-called "one-definition rule" which requires the linker to ensure there's only one definition of each function. For example, what if the function had a local static variable: there should be only one.

Comment: Thanks. I only imagined that but I was never good enough at such issues. For instance, a local static variable needs (exactly) one out of class definition, which is not the case for a function, right?

Comment: Right. `int foo() { static int count = 0; return count; }` will return a count of the number of times the function has been called. There's only one instance of the function: it only has one address. If foo is a template, declared in a header and instantiated by/into several translation units, the linker needs to remove duplicate instances of it.

Comment: @iavr Very smart solution indeed! +1 from me! I will stick with my solution as I can start the counter from a specific larger value and specialize the TypeID for some types to have same ID for those types on all platforms and also be able to use them as indices in vectors(for serialization purpose).

Comment: @Felics Fair enough. With my solution, I think it's straightforward to specialize in order to enforce same id for particular types, but otherwise you have no control on the actual values of the ids. You can only use them with `operator==` for equality comparison.

Comment: Your solution gives me over and over the same id/address for any arbitrary type. e.g. type_id<int> equals type_id<float> equals type_id<somerandomstruct>. I observed this behavior with MSVC 2015.

Comment: This solution will not work in VC++ with optimizations enabled due to COMDAT folding. In essence it's a linker optimization where all functions with an identical body will be replaced by a single function. Since `type<T>::id()` is identical for all T, it (and all other empty functions) will be replaced by a single function. This explains the behavior seen by @Julien. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx

Comment: This can be simplified to the following:
`template<typename T> struct type{static size_t id(){return reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&type<T>::id);}};`