# 'any' class implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel

I have made an `any` class in C++, base loosely on `boost::any`, but written differently. I am checking to see if I have done it correctly and that there are no mistakes in it:

```
class any
{
public:
    any()
        : dt(new data<void *>(0))
        {
        }

    template<class T>
        any(const T &value)
        : dt(new data<T>(value))
        {
        }

    any(any &rhs)
        : dt(rhs.dt->duplicate())
        {
        }

    ~any()
        {
        delete dt;
        }

    template<class T>
        T cast() const
        {
        if (type() == typeid(T))
            {
            return (reinterpret_cast<data<T> *>(dt)->val);
            }
        throw std::exception("invalid cast type");
        }

    template<class T>
        operator T() const
        {
        return (cast<T>());
        }

    template<class T>
        bool is() const
        {
        return (type() == typeid(T));
        }

    any &operator=(any &rhs)
        {
        if (this != &rhs)
            {
            delete dt;
            dt = rhs.dt->duplicate();
            }
        return (*this);
        }

    template<class T>
        any &operator=(const T &value)
        {
        delete dt;
        dt = new data<T>(value);
        return (*this);
        }

    any &swap(any &rhs)
        {
        std::swap(dt, rhs.dt);
        return (*this);
        }

    template<class T>
        bool operator==(const T &value) const
        {
        return (type() == typeid(T) &&
            cast<T>() == value);
        }

    bool operator==(any &rhs) const
        {
        return (type() == rhs.type() && 
            dt->cmp(rhs.dt));
        }

    template<class T>
        bool operator!=(const T &value) const
        {
        return (!((*this) == value));
        }

    bool operator!=(any &rhs) const
        {
        return (!((*this) == rhs));
        }

    const std::type_info &type() const
        {
        return (dt->type());
        }

protected:
    struct dummy
        {
    public:
        virtual const std::type_info &type() const = 0;
        virtual bool cmp(dummy *rhs) const = 0;
        virtual dummy *duplicate() = 0;
        };

    template<class T>
        struct data
            : public dummy
        {
    public:
        data()
            : val()
            {
            }

        data(const T &value)
            : val(value)
            {
            }

        ~data()
            {
            }

        const std::type_info &type() const
            {
            return (typeid(T));
            }

        bool cmp(dummy *rhs) const
            {
            return (val == reinterpret_cast<data<T> *>(rhs)->val);
            }

        dummy *duplicate()
            {
            return (new data<T>(val));
            }

        T val;
        };

    dummy *dt;
    };
```

Answer (score 12):

Your code is in pretty much good shape but there are still several issues apart from what mentioned by [ChrisW](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/47977/39083):

- There are many cases in input arguments and return types of functions where you are not particularly careful about `const`/non-`const` and *value vs. reference*.
- This code won't work for *built-in arrays*, hence neither for C-style strings. One way is to *decay* the type of the input argument before storage; built-in arrays are decayed to pointers in this case (which means array elements are not really copied).
- The default constructor shouldn't allocate anything; initialize the data pointer to `nullptr` and provide member functions `empty()` and `clear()` to control the *state* of having/not having data.
- Your *assignment operators* are unnecessarily complex, inefficient (by self-tests) and not exception-safe (if `new` throws, the current object is already destroyed). The most elegant solution to all these issues is the [copy-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), where all actual work is done by constructors alone.
- You don't need `typeid` to test for *type equality*; a lightweight (but low-level) solution *without RTTI* is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/45079/39083).
- *Type identification* should be kept as an internal detail; the minimal required functionality is type equality by `is()`; don't expose `type()`, rather keep it as private as possible.
- Type checking is a good thing, but for performance you should also provide *unchecked access*.
- *Casting* is from a base to a derived class, so need not (and should not) be done with `reinterpret_cast`; rather, `dynamic_cast` / `static_cast` for checked / unchecked access. `dynamic_cast` to a reference type will automatically throw an `std::bad_cast` if the object is not of the right type, so there is not need to manually check with `is()`. This does need RTTI but is more elegant.
- Storing *empty objects* (like function objects) is currently inefficient, as it does need extra space on top of the virtual function table. This can be solved by the [empty base optimization](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization), which is done automatically by using `std::tuple`.
- Implicit *conversion operators* are a possible source for ambiguities and confusion; you may keep them if you need their convenience, but use carefully (e.g. try to explicitly initialize an object of the right type).
- *Comparison operators* are a clear overkill (if you have them, why not also have arithmetic operators, and so on?). If you still want them, define them as *non-member* functions, using public members `is` and `cast` to implement them.
- There are no *move semantics*.
- There is no specialized binary (non-member) function `swap`. Defaulting to `std::swap` is not as efficient as it involves three move operations; without move semantics, things are even worse as it involves three *copy* operations.

I took the liberty to re-factor your code to a great extent, and here is the result, resolving all issues above:

```
class some
{
    using id = size_t;

    template<typename T>
    struct type { static void id() { } };

    template<typename T>
    static id type_id() { return reinterpret_cast<id>(&type<T>::id); }

    template<typename T>
    using decay = typename std::decay<T>::type;

    template<typename T>
    using none = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<some, T>::value>::type;

    struct base
    {
        virtual ~base() { }
        virtual bool is(id) const = 0;
        virtual base *copy() const = 0;
    } *p = nullptr;

    template<typename T>
    struct data : base, std::tuple<T>
    {
        using std::tuple<T>::tuple;

        T       &get()      & { return std::get<0>(*this); }
        T const &get() const& { return std::get<0>(*this); }

        bool is(id i) const override { return i == type_id<T>(); }
        base *copy()  const override { return new data{get()}; }
    };

    template<typename T>
    T &stat() { return static_cast<data<T>&>(*p).get(); }

    template<typename T>
    T const &stat() const { return static_cast<data<T> const&>(*p).get(); }

    template<typename T>
    T &dyn() { return dynamic_cast<data<T>&>(*p).get(); }

    template<typename T>
    T const &dyn() const { return dynamic_cast<data<T> const&>(*p).get(); }

public:
     some() { }
    ~some() { delete p; }

    some(some &&s)      : p{s.p} { s.p = nullptr; }
    some(some const &s) : p{s.p->copy()} { }

    template<typename T, typename U = decay<T>, typename = none<U>>
    some(T &&x) : p{new data<U>{std::forward<T>(x)}} { }

    some &operator=(some s) { swap(*this, s); return *this; }

    friend void swap(some &s, some &r) { std::swap(s.p, r.p); }

    void clear() { delete p; p = nullptr; }

    bool empty() const { return p; }

    template<typename T>
    bool is() const { return p ? p->is(type_id<T>()) : false; }

    template<typename T> T      &&_()     && { return std::move(stat<T>()); }
    template<typename T> T       &_()      & { return stat<T>(); }
    template<typename T> T const &_() const& { return stat<T>(); }

    template<typename T> T      &&cast()     && { return std::move(dyn<T>()); }
    template<typename T> T       &cast()      & { return dyn<T>(); }
    template<typename T> T const &cast() const& { return dyn<T>(); }

    template<typename T> operator T     &&()     && { return std::move(_<T>()); }
    template<typename T> operator T      &()      & { return _<T>(); }
    template<typename T> operator T const&() const& { return _<T>(); }
};
```

I call it `some` instead of `any` because I prefer to hold `some`thing rather than `any`thing :-) Plus, `any` is a common name for a function (like `all`), which is not the case for `some`.

Members `cast()` provide type-checked access, while members `_()` (shortest notation) provide unchecked access. I have chosen to give conversion operators unchecked access for performance but you are free to change that or remove them altogether.

I've also made a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5eab9499d50e829), including an extensive series of tests to demonstrate (almost) all possible uses.

Note that `base` (your `dummy`) now has a `virtual` destructor.

There is one more issue: using the *free store* is serious performance bottleneck when it comes to small types. What you can do is define a particular size to be allocated on *stack*, and only use the free store for larger objects, similar to [short (or small) string optimization](http://john-ahlgren.blogspot.gr/2012/03/small-string-optimization-and-move.html).

More generally, it is a good idea to parametrize the implementation with respect to how memory management (allocation, deallocation) is done by providing a kind of *allocator* object. `any` is really a *container*, even if of at most one object.

I have extended the implementation towards this direction but I will probably post this as a separate answer.

Comment: I eventually completed what I had promised and I posted it as a new *question*: [Yet another 'any'](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/48344/39083).

Answer (score 6):

> I am checking to see if I have done it correctly and that there are no mistakes in it:

What have you done to test this class? You might want to write some unit-tests.

---

I think I see at least one bug: the destructor ...

```
    ~any()
    {
    delete dt;
    }
```

... calls `delete dt`.

`dt` seems to be of type `dummy*` ...

```
dummy *dt;
```

... but is actually of type `data<T>` which derives from `dummy`.

`dummy` is defined without a virtual destructor: so when you call `delete dt` then the `dummy` destructor will be called but the `data` destructor won't be called, and therefore the `T` data member of the `data` destructor won't be called, which is a bug if `T` has a non-trivial (non-default) destructor.

---

I don't see why you don't define `duplicate` as a `const` method, and define the `any(any &rhs)` constructor and the `any &operator=(any &rhs)` operator as taking `const` reference parameters.

---

You defined the implementation details of `any` as `protected` instead of `private`, as if you expect `any` to be subclassed. If `any` will be subclassed then its methods (e.g. its destructor) should perhaps be `virtual`.

---

You implemented `operator T() const` which is a conversion operator; but boost implements an explicit function i.e. `any_cast` for this purpose. I'm not sure why boost chose the latter but it may be better for some reason: perhaps it's safer because it's more explicit.

boost define a custom exception type `bad_any_cast` if the cast fails; you're just using a `std::exception` which might be harder to catch accurately.

Comment: boost uses the cast convention as they did not want automatic (compiler generated) conversion from an `Any<T>` to a `T`

Comment: @LokiAstari Yes, but can you guess at why they didn't want automatic conversion?

Comment: At a guess: Auto conversion in general is a bad idea (obvious few exceptions).