# Unique type ID, no RTTI

Tags: c++, c++11, rtti

Following my answer to [Unique type ID in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44936/unique-type-id-in-c/45079#45079), I have worked towards a "safer" version that I am posting here.

This is a lightweight type that can store a unique (also across compilation units) ID per type for use at runtime, without RTTI.

Instead of using a built-in type for ID representation that is also accessible to the end user, a specific class `type_id_t` provides the external representation of the ID and encapsulates the actual storage type (a function pointer) that is *not* accessible.

A helper function template call `type_id<T>()` returns a `type_id_t` containing the ID of type `T`.

Hence, the following operations are only provided:

- construction *only* by calling `type_id` function.
- copy/move construction, as implicitly defined
- copy/move assignment, as implicitly defined
- comparison operators `==` and `!=` between two `type_id_t`'s

There is no default constructor for `type_id_t`.

Here is the implementation:

```
class type_id_t
{
    using sig = type_id_t();

    sig* id;
    type_id_t(sig* id) : id{id} {}

public:
    template<typename T>
    friend type_id_t type_id();

    bool operator==(type_id_t o) const { return id == o.id; }
    bool operator!=(type_id_t o) const { return id != o.id; }
};

template<typename T>
type_id_t type_id() { return &type_id<T>; }
```

It is interesting that function `type_id` returns a (function) pointer to *itself*, encapsulated into a `type_id_t`. No nasty type casting is necessary.

This is *not* a mechanism that provides runtime identification of a (polymorphic) object's type, but can be used as a low-level tool to build such functionality. I actually made this for the needs of my recent [any](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/48344/39083), and then improved it.

Just for demonstration, we can store the ID of a number of types e.g. in a vector:

```
template<typename... T>
std::vector<type_id_t>
make_ids() { return {type_id<T>()...}; }
```

Later, we can compare the stored IDs to the ID of a given type:

```
template<typename T, typename A>
void comp_ids(const A& a)
{
    for (auto i : a)
        std::cout << (type_id<T>() == i) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

and get the following:

```
auto ids = make_ids<
    int, bool, double const&, int&&, char(&)[8],
    int, void(int), unsigned char**, std::vector<void(*)()>, double[4][8]
>();

comp_ids<int>(ids);  // output: 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Here is a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0bc04694678beaf).

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: the type id trick won't work across shared libraries.

Comment: @user1095108 Are you sure? I have posted a [specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23437965/2644390) on this. There has been some discussion and it appears that it will work. Bottomline is that templates are defined as weak symbols and are merged into one definition at link time according to iso 3.2/5.

Comment: Hi, is there any way, how to access type of type_id<T> later in the class? For debug purposes, would be great to be able to access some stringable object id (not pointer address). In VisualStudio, I see that sig has type t1 = {id=0x01bfdc52 {type_id<struct `....stTest>(void)} }. But I'm not able to get this value through typeid() in any way. Thanks.

Comment: @iavr This doesn't work with dynamic **loading** (dlopen/dlsym) but _does_ work with dynamic linking. RTTI still works in the former case based on my small testing (which is by no means exhaustive)

Answer (score 7):

The first thing I notice when looking at this code is the lack of documentation.

I would provide some more operators. Specifically I would go for `operator<` so `type_id_t` is usable as key for `std::map` and you should think about specializing `std::hash` so the class can be used with hash maps.

As the code is pretty short I don't find any more to say about it.

Btw.: Well done. I like this solution very much.

Comment: Thanks, very good point about `operator<` and `std::hash`! I thought `==` and `!=` should be enough for *identification*, but being able to use ID as key in an associative container sounds very essential. As for documentation, this is my weakest point--I only *hope* this page could be seen as some form of documentation :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is very nice, however, I usually just use:

```
using typeid_t = void const*;

template <typename T>
typeid_t type_id() noexcept
{
  static char const type_id;

  return &type_id;
}
```

The `void const*` pointers can be compared and hashed and cannot be dereferenced without casting. Good enough for me. The solution also avoids casts, just like your question.

Alternatively:

```
using typeid_t = void(*)();

template <typename T>
typeid_t type_id() noexcept
{
  return typeid_t(type_id<T>);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work across the shared libraries. The one with the function template instantiation address does work however.

Comment: could be you did not export the function. Anyway, I've provided an alternative now.

Comment: Doesn't work with VS :( it always return same address.

Comment: @DawidDrozd if you instantiate it with the same `T`, this is what it should do.

Comment: @user1095108 nope with different T don't work see yourself... https://rextester.com/QGW35526

Comment: @DawidDrozd put `static` in front of the function definition, there's always a way around vc++ strangeness. I always use this function as a class member not as a free function.

Comment: @user1095108 seems to work but still I'm not so sure about it. We will see ;)

Comment: `static char` trick works ok, I don't know why you are complicating, there are other approaches too, including a `constexpr` typeid, google for it.